# Hp Thin Client printing

Tags: printing

I'm trying to figure out how to add a local printer on the HP Thin Client t5145 so I can use it for LPD printing. The local OS on the thin client is linux. I'm trying to print from a RDP session on win2003server. On the older model thin clients there was a check box for "enable LPD printing" for the printer. I cannot find this option anywhere on the thin client. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which OS are you running on the thin client?  Is it an XPe device?  Linux?

Comment: I am running linux on the thin clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'm just accustomed to our old thin clients. After I added the printer as a lpd port, I never rebooting the thin client. That was the problem. As soon as I rebooted the thin client and re-added the lpr ports on the server, everything worked fine. *Slap* myself for not trying the faithful reboot.